# C compiler not recognizing unsigned long

Tags: c, long-integer, implicit-conversion, unsigned, unsigned-integer

On my computer, `long` takes a maximum value of `9223372036854775807`. However, when I tired `unsigned long` with a larger value the compiler throws a warning saying it needs to be interpreted as an `unsigned long` when I already had it defined as so. Why is that the case?

```
//assigning maximum value of a long integer. (No error)
long max_l = 9223372036854775807L;

//assigning an unsigned long integer.
unsigned long max_ul = 9223372036854775808L; //warning: integer literal is too large to be represented in a signed
                                             //integer type, interpreting as unsigned [-Wimplicitly-unsigned-literal]
```

---

```
cc --version
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
```

Comment: You can **remove** the prefix.

Comment: Note that, assuming the system has 64-bit `long` and no larger extended integer types, this code behaves differently in C90 than in later editions.  In C90 the constant would have type `unsigned long` even though the suffix is `L`, whereas since C99 the decimal constant without `u` can only ever have a signed type (with it being a constraint violation if no suitable type exists).  So it is relevant in which mode you are invoking the compiler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This integer constant:

```
9223372036854775808L
```

is too large to be stored in a `long`.

Instead, use:

```
9223372036854775808UL
```

This specifies that the constant has the type `unsigned long` by appending the suffix `UL`

Or just use the suffix `U`:

```
unsigned long max_ul = 9223372036854775808U;
```

When an integer constant has the suffix `L` (or `l`) then the compiler determines its type in the following order: the first of the types

```
signed long
signed long long
```

in which its value can be represented. It seems that the type `signed long` has the same integer representation as the type `signed long long` established by the compiler. So neither the type `signed long` nor the type `signed long long` can represent the constant. The constant is too big for these types. But the type `unsigned long` that has the same internal representation as the type `unsigned long long` established by the compiler can represent the constant.

Pay also attention to that there are no negative integer constants in C.
If for example you will write

```
int x = -1;
```

then the compiler splits the construction `-1` into two tokens: the integer constant `1` and the unary operator `-`.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 0, 1, 2 };
    int *p = a + 1;

    printf( "p[-1] = %d\n", p[-1] );
    printf( "-1[p] = %d\n", -1[p] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
p[-1] = 0
-1[p] = -2
```

The expression `-1[p]` is not the same as the expression `(-1)[p]`. It is processed as `-(1[p] )` that is equivalent to `-p[1]`.

Comment: Yep. That works. Also note that ```%lu``` needs to be used as the formatter to print the correct number.

Answer (score 3):

Every integer constant such as `9223372036854775808` has a type of its own. There's some rules for what types the compiler pick for integer constants in your program. For plain decimal constants (without any U, L suffix), it goes like this:

- Try if it fits inside `int`.
- If not, try if it fits inside `long`.
- If not, try if it fits inside `long long`.

(See the table in C17 6.4.4.1 for details)

Apparently all of these checks failed for the value 2^63 on your system, which is to be expected since a signed 64 bit only goes up to 2^63 - 1.

Adding `L` doesn't solve anything, because that only tells the compiler to do the above checks but start with `long`.

Declaring the type where you will store the integer constant as unsigned doesn't solve anything, because the type to the left of the assignment/initialization has nothing to do with the type of the integer constant. You could write `my_custom_type x = 9223372036854775808L;` and you'd get the same warning.

The obvious solution is to to use unsigned suffix `U`. Otherwise, if you for some reason need >63 value bit signed, you'd need to find some 128 bit signed "big int" library, which would be far more painful.